# ignore "blank" (unfilled) row with jackson csv

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I can't find a way to ignore "blank" lines in a CSV. I use quotes because I'm talking about lines that look like `'','','','',''` or `,,,,,,` Here is a CSV (blank lines could be random):

```
id,name,age
1,alex,22
3,tiff,42
,,
,,
4,john,24
```

What I expect is output list of POJO will contain only these data

```
1,alex,22
3,tiff,42
4,john,24
```

Here is similar questions that I've been reading, but different to this in particular: [JACKSON :: SKIP_EMPTY_LINES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537242/how-to-get-mappingiterator-to-not-include-empty-rows)

Have tried out multiple approaches didn't find any csv mapper feature inbuilt. Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you please share your **attempt** to the file as well as your POJO. Use the *edit* button or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74776992/edit) to update the question.